# Setup Ant to use JDK different from one specified in JAVA_HOME

Tags: ant

So for reason of running many projects, I don't want to change JAVA_HOME variable (1.6) but I would like ant to run and use 1.5 JDK.

I have manage to do this from Eclipse IDE (so it can be done), so when running from Eclipse IDE it will use 1.5 since I specified JDK 1.5 as project's JDK.

To make long story short I want Ant when run from cmd prompt to use JDK 1.5.

Seems pretty easy but I am having trouble finding out the way to do it.

P.S.

Reason I need this to work from command prompt is because ant build is quite long 3-4 mins and my Eclipse IDE gets frozen while it's running. Three minutes waits are simply not acceptable :)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own script, called ant2 or similar, to execute ant from the JDK that you want and add it into the PATH.

Comment: Good idea, I will do that for now. If there is no better solutions  I will mark it as accepted :) Thank you

Comment: Sometimes simple ideas are the best. Following KISS principle!