# Why is ant looking for tools.jar in the wrong dir?

Tags: ant, java

I am trying to execute `ant -version' and I get

```
C:\Users\owner>ant -version
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\tools.jar
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
```

I checked all of my environment variables and I cant find a reference to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`

I have the JDK and JRE installed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10`

I also have stuff in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10`

Can anyone tell me why ant is looking in the wrong directory?

I have seen a bunch of other questions on stackoverflow but none of them solve my issue.

output of %path% is

```
C:\Users\owner>echo %path%
%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Window
s;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\CyberLink\Power2Go;C:\Program
Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Window
s\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;C:\Prog
ram Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10;C:\Program Fil
es (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\A
ndroid\android-sdk\platform-tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\to
ols\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live

C:\Users\owner>echo %JAVA_HOME%
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jdk1.7.0_10
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo %PATH%` in the command prompt where you are running ant?

Comment: updated question with `echo %path%`

Comment: I was going to tell you to post the `JAVA_HOME` output too but someone has already posted an answer based on that.

Comment: Okay seems like you updated your question. Since your environment variables are tallying out, can you also post your ant build/configuration file?

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake. I was assuming you are running a build under ant. An ant project usually has a build.xml file associated with it. If you are looking to run ant under a specific JDK/JRE you can try the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913467/setup-ant-to-use-jdk-different-from-one-specified-in-java-home . Also ensure that your ant environment variables are set as per the apache ant documentation under the section "Check Installation" at http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just figured out what it was

changing %JAVA_HOME% from `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jdk1.7.0_10` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_10` fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

Ant does (unfortunately) rely on the `JAVA_HOME` system property. You will want to make sure that this property points to a valid JDK installation (and not a JRE).

Comment: I've updated my question with the output of `%JAVA_HOME%`