# Ant using 2 different JDK's

Tags: java, ant

I am looking to compile some ADF applications in addition to some custom java.

To compile the ADF applications I want to use the same JDK that was used to develop it, ie 1.6.

I then wish to compile AND run some custom java in 1.7.

Is it possible to get Ant to use different JDK's in the same/different scripts? 
What I was thining was to set JAVA_HOME to be the 1.6 JDK as this is what I want to use be used as default.

For the custom java I was then going to set another environment variable to 1.7 JDK and then I want ant to reference this JDK in a specific target.

Comment: possible duplicate of:[Setup Ant to use JDK different from one specified in JAVA_HOME](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7913746/3309790)

Comment: The solution in that was to basically modify the ant framework which I do not want to do.